# Is イングリッシュ a good translation of "Engrish"?

Tags: translation, terminology

Is イングリッシュ a good translation of Engrish?

The Japanese-language Wikipedia [article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engrish) on the subject only uses "イングリッシュ" at the start (presumably just as part of Wikipedia indicating how the subject of articles are pronounced). When trying a google web search, many hits were referring to English schools referring to English, not Engrish (for example english-bell.com), and a google image search mainly gets hits for Johnny English, or the English cocker spaniel.

If it's not a good translation, what words or phrases, if any, are likely to be easily understood, preferably without being offensive?

Comment: No. It's just a pronunciation, not a translation.

Comment: @marasai

No, it is a transliteration, not a pronunciation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Japanese have a term equivalent to "Engrish"?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2869/does-japanese-have-a-term-equivalent-to-engrish)

Comment: @broccoliforest isn't that describing the opposite - low quality Japanese, not low quality English?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Ah! I misread that question. That's what I somehow felt weird...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Translating *Engrish* in Japanese is no easier than pulling yourself up by your bootstrap, since they use it while they don't notice using it. (Transcribing *Engrish* would face the same paradox, too.)

So, basically you should explain instead of translating. The first sentence in your Wikipedia link shows one of the most thorough samples.

> 日本人が日本語の文章を英語に翻訳を<sup>[*sic*]</sup>する時、あるいは英語で文章を書こうとした時に生み出された、語法・文法・綴り・語彙などの点で奇妙な英語表現

But for the sake of brevity, you can just express it as 「（日本人の）変な英語」「怪しい英語」「奇妙な英語」 etc.

You could throw a visual knuckleball like イングりッシュ (cf. トイザらス *Toys"R"Us*), which might convey the intended oddity but not guaranteed to be understood as you expect, either.

Answer (score -5):

In this case, the word **イングリッシュ** is much more acceptable.

The term is a bit derogatory though.

Comment: Much more acceptable than what?

Comment: Much more acceptable than any other "Engrish". Though instead of using the Katakana, the spelling "Engrish" in itself already a meaning in itself.